# Comments are diplaying on every post django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Hey guys I am trying to make a comment form in django but the problem I am facing is that while posting that comment ,It gets posted on every other post ..
I want it to be specific to the post where the user will coment as a normal comment form works.

Here's the views.py

```
def BlogDetail(request,pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk = pk) 
    comment_view = Comment.objects.all()
    comment = CommentForm()

    if request.method  == 'POST':

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit = False)
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog',pk = post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return render(request,'app/blog.html',{'blog_object':post,'comment':comment,
                                         'comment_view':comment_view})
```

Here's the html code

```
{% for i in comment_view %}
                <p>{{i.name}}</p>
                <p>{{i.body}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
```

Here's the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hastags

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Comment: their is no need to use comment = CommentForm() because you already using form at the end, you can remove any one line from your code

Comment: But my actual problem isn,t solved yet

Comment: actually I'm still trying to understand the problem, do you want the comments of a specific post below it?

Comment: when I posta comment.It gets posted on my every post.That,s the problem i am facing

Comment: actually you didn't added a foreign key to connect the comments to a specific model

Comment: So can you rewrite it

Comment: edit your question and provide the post and comments code

Comment: what you want me to write? can you give more information about it

Comment: I mean I want you to write my code right,So it can function properly

Comment: Mr Ivan Starostin ,I did it but now it,s giving me an another error

Comment: give me 5 minutes I'm writing the code

Comment: I tried the answer but now it shows no comments

Comment: Did you link any of previously created comments to a post? Review your database contents.

Comment: I have posted the answer with comment model and a method to call the comments directly into your template

Answer (score 2):

Your `Comment` model is missing FK (foreign key)/link to Post so all the comments are not linked to anything. You need to add `post` field to `Comment` model, link it to `Post` model,

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)  # <<<
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

provide `post_id` value when creating comments and then update your query code as follows:

```
comment_view = Comment.objects.all()
```

=>

```
comment_view = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=pk, )
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'post_id' into field. Choices are: body, id, name

Comment: @UbaidParvez can you share your models.py code for post and comment

Comment: class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

Comment: @UbaidParvez update your question with this info please.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(article=self)


class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.comment



def BlogDetail(request,pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk = pk) 

    if request.method  == 'POST':    
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)    
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit = False)
            form.article = post
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog',pk = post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        context = {
            'post': post,
            'form' : form,
        }

    return render(request,'app/blog.html', context)    


    {% for comment in post.get_comments %}
        <p>{{comment.user}}</p>
        <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: what happen? Can you tell the problem

Comment: My comment form is displaying because I enjected that through django templates and now I assigned the value of commentForm to variable but still now I am not able to see that on page

Comment: Can you show me what changes you have done in your code?

Comment: @UbaidParvez if you want to pass the form through views then you can check my updated code

Comment: Should we move this problem to chat room so that we can discuss it their and the question and answer will not get messy

Comment: sorry about that, but we can move to https://chat.stackoverflow.com and discuss the problem their

Comment: yeah we should move to chat room

Comment: so then you can share your here

Answer (score 0):

Here,s the change I made in views.py

```
def BlogDetail(request,pk):

        post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk = pk)
        form = CommentForm()

        if request.method  == 'POST':

            form = CommentForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form = form.save(commit = False)
                form.article = post
                form.user = request.user
                form.save()
                return redirect('blog',pk = post.pk)
            else:
                form = CommentForm()  

        return render(request,'app/blog.html',{'blog_object':post,'comment':form,
    })
```

And here is the changes I made in models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.comment
```

Comment: So, finally you don't need to see comments at all, right?

Comment: did you check my answer, I have made a def get_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(article=self) method in post model and it can directly call your comments

Comment: You are not getting it man,My comments are displaying well but the problem is that It displays on every post say for e.g I commented on post 1 ,But it displays that comment on Post2 also and Post3....etc That,s what my problem is

Comment: You have two working solutions here. Have another look at answers provided and your code.

Comment: brother, you are not understanding the solution, we have provided you a solution that must work, either try this method "get_comments" in my solution or the queryset solution by Ivan